# How do i connect the firebase Firestore to my swift app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried many different resources online but they all seem to use app delegate files and I get TOTALLY confused.

All I want to be able to do is read and write from the cloud firestore to my swift app

I have installed firebase and the firestore via the package manager and it can't seem to find the Firestore Manager

```
 import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main

struct RecipyApp: App{
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var firestoreManager = FirestoreManager()

    
    var body: some Scene{
        let viewModel = AppViewModel()
        WindowGroup{
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
                .environmentObject(firestoreManager)
   
                
        }
        
    }
    
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate{
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        
        return true
        
    }
}
```

MY CODE.

What can I do to fix my problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it better

Comment: You have to make the Firestone Manager

Comment: @loremipsum wdym

Comment: What I said it doesn’t come from Firebase you have to make it. You’ve likely copied this code from somewhere. Go back there and read the tutorial, post, watch the video, etc.

Comment: @loremipsum i have coppied the tutorial word for word

Comment: Find the FirebaseManager class. They likely provide it in the sample code or tell you how to make it. Don’t just copy the code follow the tutorial, you are missing something.

Comment: Yeah - I agree with @loremipsum. Firebase doesn't have a `FirestoreManager` so it must be something like a class or struct created in the tutorial or a 3rd party library required by the tutorial. Perhaps something like this offsite tutorial [FirebaseManager](https://designcode.io/swiftui-advanced-handbook-write-to-firestore). Just a guess though. Oh - so you know Firestore has their own snappy [Getting Started with Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) tutorial. You should take a look there.

Comment: @jay but the docs uses an app delegate which confuses me

Comment: The official docs as linked about do not use an app delegate. However in some cases if you're crafting a SwiftUI app, an AppDelegate is implemented to bridge those. If you're referring to some other off site tutorial, stop using it and go through the getting started guide first and then maybe re-look at that tutorial.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/quick-code/step-by-step-guide-to-use-firebase-firestore-in-an-ios-app-749c5254a27b) guide once.

Comment: Why didn't you install Firebase using CocoaPods? May I suggest starting over and installing with CocoaPods? I suspect you made a mistake importing manually with the package manager. From there, I can easily walk you through the setup which is very basic.

Answer (score -2):

Solution 1:

- Delete The Excess Package And Run The App

Solution 2:

- Go To Xcode Preference > Location, Delete Derived Data

Comment: how do i re ad the packages then?

Comment: That Show An Error Named :"Missing Package" ,  Then Add That package